# How to access then name property of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

After some research I found out the way to access this Array through mapping would be something like

```
const locations = [
    {
      country: "United States",
      city: "Henderson",
      state: "Kentucky",
      postalCode: 42420,
    
    },
    {
     
      country: "United States",
      city: "Henderson",
      state: "Kentucky",
      postalCode: 42420,
     
    }]

locations.map((item)=>{<p>{item.city}</p>})
```

Suppose for the above case I want to get the name such as **country** ,**city** eh how do I go about to extract those object *titles* .
I have gone through several documentations and resources but i have not found a clear solution

Comment: `Object.entries(item)`

Comment: @FlashThunder `map` doesn't modify the array, it creates a new one.

Comment: `Array` is the array constructor; don't name a variable after built-in types.

Comment: `map` is used for creating a new array with the same length as the one you're iterating over through, not for modifying / mutating an array. How you populate that array is up to the developer when writing the specific implementation. In this use case the OP is creating an array of jsx elements

Comment: @FlashThunder that is incorrect. In React a very common pattern is to map over an array and return JSX to render. This is producing output

Comment: @FlashThunder "it shouldn't be used to produce output" Well, I would disagree. It should only be used to produce the output :)

Comment: ok, well... EOT for me then, removed my comments, as I guess we don't understand eachother... JSX is not output. It does produce output in farther steps. Probably thats the difference of thinking of pure js vs react js dev. I am talking about what's under react.

Comment: @cocosa: questions should include a clear description of both desired and actual results. As it stands, what you want (and why what you have doesn't meet that) is unclear.

Comment: "JSX is not output." ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ JSX is a syntax extension, but the result of the transpilation is a function call that returns an object. So I am still not able to get how you come to the conclusion that from react's point of view map is not for producing output.

Answer (score 3):

in the map you should return the object by the removing the curly brackets

```
locations.map(item => <p>{item.city}</p> )
```

or if you keep the curly brackets add an explicit `return`

```
locations.map(item => { return <p>{item.city}</p> })
```

If you would like to add more to what is displayed on the page you can add more fields in the map's return

```
locations.map(item => <p>{item.country}, {item.city}, {item.state}, {item.postalCode}</p> )
```

Comment: Yes the above is true but is it possible now to get the title of that object dynamically for your case the title would be "city"  ,"country" eg

Comment: @cocosa just add more to the output? `<p>{item.country}, {item.city}</p>`

Comment: Yes thank you but this will not give me the title being referenced by the "item" like for example i want to get the "Object.key" title

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you would like to use the property names as labels? If so you'll need to iterate the `Object.keys()` or `Object.entries()` of each item as a nested `map()` call. You'll need a containing component to hold it, here an outer `<div>` element.

```
const locations = [
  {
    country: 'United States',
    city: 'Henderson',
    state: 'Kentucky',
    postalCode: 42420,
  },
];

locations.map((item) => (
  <div key={item.unique_property}>
    {Object.entries(item).map((label, value) => (
      <p>
        <span>{label}: </span>{value}
      </p>
    ))}
  </div>
));
```

Which will output something like the following

```
<div>
  <p><span>country: </span>United States</p>
  <p><span>city: </span>Henderson</p>
  <p><span>state: </span>Kentucky</p>
  <p><span>postalCode: </span>42420</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below should work didn't tested though .

```
{locations.map((val) =>
    Object.keys(val?.fields).map((field) => (
      <p key={field}>
        Key : {field}
        Value:{val?.fields[field]}
      </p>
    ))
  )}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).